# Single page bootstrap website skipping sections

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, portfolio

I am currently working on one of those single page portfolio-like sites using Bootstrap and have run into an annoying problem.

I use the buttons on the navbar to go to specific sections of the single page site, but for some reason one of the sections has its title being cut off.

Here is how it appears:  [image]

Here is how I would like it appear: [image]

Not sure if relevant, but here is the code for the buttons on the navbar:

```
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1" >
            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website name</a></li>
        
                <li>
                    <a href="#about" >About Us</a>
                </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#submissions">Submissions </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#contact">Contact Us </a>
              </li>
        </ul>
```

And here is the initial code for the Submissions section:

```
    <section id="submissions" class="submissions">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center"><h2>Submissions</h2></div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
```

(Everything under that is just the content and closing all the tags.)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a fixed nav bar you will need to account for the space it takes up and add padding. When the navbar is fixed, it is not a part of the DOM and therefore your section titles will be displayed at the top of the screen, but hidden under the nav  bar.

Try adding body{padding-top: 50px} to your css and see if that allows the display of the section headings.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to add a spacer (probably a `<div>` width some specific height) on the top of your first section

Answer (score 0):

There could be many cases as to why your anchor link isn't displaying properly. 
Given your example, the safest assumption (and the mistake I most commonly make) is to forget to add top padding to my body element when my navbar is fixed.

[Gavgrif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5867572/gavgrif)'s answer solves this issue.

If this is not the case, CSS Tricks has an awesome article regarding Anchor Links and their behaviour, which can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/).

The article gives several examples and "tricks" that make handling the anchor position easier. In summary, you should include the anchor (id="submissions") inside of the heading as follows:

```
<section class="submissions">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
          <h2>
              <span name="submissions" id="submissions"></span>
              Submissions
          </h2>
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
```

This HTML allows you to add negative top margin to the span, and positive bottom margin to the heading in various amounts to exactly position the anchor point to where you would like.

This "trick" has its obvious flaws in semantics and several other things, but there is also a "CSS-Only" trick provided in the article, granted it is less supported by older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

hi i believe nav menu is on fixed position. you can just move your id="submission" to element inside container. or you can use jquery to make something cooler like this

```js
$("#btn-submission").click(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#submission').offset().top - 50
   }, 500);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="btn-submission" href="javascript:void(0)">Submission</a>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="submission">
  <h2>Submission</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis lectus vitae enim tincidunt pellentesque. Fusce felis lorem, laoreet quis quam eget, sagittis ornare massa. Vivamus sit amet massa sit amet lacus efficitur feugiat elementum a massa. Nunc id fermentum turpis. Phasellus in molestie nulla. Pellentesque eget sem non velit tempus vestibulum in ac tortor. Aliquam ultricies diam ut dui ullamcorper, et scelerisque felis consectetur. In auctor massa ac turpis tristique lacinia. Maecenas quis suscipit neque.
</p></div>
<div id="others">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis quis lectus vitae enim tincidunt pellentesque. Fusce felis lorem, laoreet quis quam eget, sagittis ornare massa. Vivamus sit amet massa sit amet lacus efficitur feugiat elementum a massa. Nunc id fermentum turpis. Phasellus in molestie nulla. Pellentesque eget sem non velit tempus vestibulum in ac tortor. Aliquam ultricies diam ut dui ullamcorper, et scelerisque felis consectetur. In auctor massa ac turpis tristique lacinia. Maecenas quis suscipit neque.</div>
```